# Referencing state from within state - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to reference state from within state to create an id. e.g id = this.state.name + this.state.desc

Something like this?

```
this.state = {name:'', desc:'', id:`${this.state.name}-${this.state.desc}`}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Depends where are you doing it. If within a class body, you will receive an error.

Comment: I think you can't since state is not yet initialized. But you will know where to get those values, so you can simply set id when your state is updated

Comment: i think it's possible if you're writing multiple assignments in the constructor, but i wouldn't do it. it feels like an anti-pattern, but without knowing the whole context idk what to suggest here. (this also feels more like a code review question than SE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you need to set the state using `setState`

So

```
this.setState({ id:`${this.state.name}-${this.state.desc}` })
```

This is also assuming that you have already set the state in the constructor (or somewhere else int he app).

If you are in the constructor, then this should work just fine...

```
this.state = { name: 'Toli', desc: 'A programmer' };
this.state = {...this.state, id:`${this.state.name}-${this.state.desc}`}
```

I'm assuming you want to keep `name` and `desc` in the state so I'm copying them using the spread op (`...this.state`)

Comment: you can, and should, set state without `setState` in the constructor

Comment: @worc - but if the OP is trying to use `this.state = {....}` and reference `this.state` inside it, then they are obviously not doing it in the constructor as the state has been previously defined.

Comment: I think that's the point. He is trying to do it in the constructor.

Comment: you could have multiple lines of `this.state = ... ` and then i think you could *technically* do what they're asking. it wouldn't be very idiomatic though.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that won't work. `this.state` is initialized before the constructor, but it won't like that you are referencing an undefined portion of the object. You would need to set it after initialization. I'm assuming you would be using `this.state = {blah}` from your constructor. Otherwise, you should use `this.setState()`.

However this is also bad practice because anytime you update your name or desc, it will update the state again with your new id value. I don't know the full scope of your code, but you can probably just save the id to a function that gives you the string.